# Is there a successor to PDF that is page-agnostic?

Tags: pdf, download, page, save

I would like to give my users the ability to download the content but I am reluctant to use PDF. I believe that PDF these days should long be treated as an archaism for its focus on being purported to be printed out and, thus, being laid out on pages with fixed dimensions.

So, I am after a newer, page-agnostic portable format for offline document viewing on digital devices for those who have put their printers up the attic long ago and have developed an allergy to seeing paper pages on their device screens.

Web pages saved from browsers often work acceptably, but there are issues:

- usually *many* files are saved: HTML, styles, images, scripts etc. Need just one for portability convenience.
- when opened, these pages will attempt to link from the Internet whatever was linked from 3rd party websites. A truly portable document should never try to do that and should look the same regardless of whether the device is connected to the Internet.
- there is no system for metadata and integrity checks (e.g. hashing, digital signatures etc.)

Before I start inventing the would-be wheel, I'd like to know if there is anything done already in this direction. Anything?

Comment: And what is wrong with HTML itself? It was always defined from the get go as being display agnostic. As long as they have a browser. You can save all the contents in an archive, see HAR file format, so the content can be made completely offline. As for metadata, there is the HTML `<meta>` tag and integrity checks exist as well (see Subresource Integrity specification at https://www.w3.org/TR/SRI/)

Comment: @PatrickMevzek Didn't know about HAR. It might be the answer.

Comment: Also some tools are able to "mirror" a website by fetching all resources AND converting links so that they become "internal"/local and not trigger a new remote query. See `wget --mirror` for example.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek It seems like both HAR and mirror end up with the viewer's browser making actual HTTP calls to display the content, albeit those are all local. Whilst the user won't notice, technically it doesn't feel to be the answer: ideally, the format needs to be rendered without the need to call the network stack.

Comment: "ideally, the format needs to be rendered without the need to call the network stack." That is not a consideration for the format itself. The thing that create the content from download should just make sure all links are like `<a href="./second.hml">` and then there is 0 network call at loading time. Otherwise you will need to give actual examples of what you have in mind. There are network calls only if URLs start with `http://`,`https://`, `ftp://` etc. If it starts by nothing or `file:///` this is purely local. Of course both javascript, fonts, images, etc. need to be "fixed" like that.

Answer (score 2):

When I think "PDF but page agnostic", my mind immediately goes to e-book file formats, for example [EPUB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EPUB).

EPUB is an open file format that supports rich formatting and has wide compatibility with e-book reader hardware as well as phone and tablet apps. Like all popular e-book file formats, an EPUB file contains an entire document and is generally self-contained in its appearance, though it has the ability to embed outbound links to the internet.

Basically, EPUB is a complete, self-contained HTML-based format that's portable, pageless, and optimized for text and images.

The only real downside is that I believe most OSes don't have built-in support for reading these type of files and require third-party e-book reader software, so if I were to offer EPUB files to my users, I would also offer them the option of downloading a PDF file too - just in case someone wants to save and read the content without installing additional software.